# What is the command to export table as CSV in spatialite

Tags: export, csv, spatialite

I need to do two steps on command line in Spatialite: 
 1. remove duplicate rows from a table and then 
 2. export table as CSV

Both of these are available in the GUI, but how do I do that on the command line?

Comment: Not sure this is really a GIS question, but anyway, to answer the 2nd question, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-a-query-as-a-csv-file Removing duplicates is in general quite easy in SQL. Have you tried/searched anything?

Answer (score 1):

got it - never mind:

**To export** an SQLite table (or part of a table) as CSV, simply set the "mode" to "csv" and then run a query to extract the desired rows of the table.

```
sqlite> .header on 
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1; 
sqlite> .system c:/work/dataout.csv
```

In the example above, the ".header on" line causes column labels to be printed as the first row of output. This means that the first row of the resulting CSV file will contain column labels. If column labels are not desired, set ".header off" instead. (The ".header off" setting is the default and can be omitted if the headers have not been previously turned on.)

The line ".once FILENAME" causes all query output to go into the named file instead of being printed on the console. In the example above, that line causes the CSV content to be written into a file named "C:/work/dataout.csv".

The final line of the example (the ".system c:/work/dataout.csv") has the same effect as double-clicking on the c:/work/dataout.csv file in windows. This will typically bring up a spreadsheet program to display the CSV file. That command only works as shown on Windows. The equivalent line on a Mac would be ".system open /work/dataout.csv". On Linux and other unix systems you will need to enter something like ".system libreoffice /work/dataout.csv", substituting your preferred CSV viewing program for "libreoffice".

**To remove duplicates:**
use SELECT DISTINCT operand - that removes duplicate rows on the creation of the table.